# Тормозит змейка в Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

Написал змейку. В Windows 7 все работает нормально, в Ubuntu 14.04 она тормозит. ОЗУ на ноутбуке 8 Gb. И в Windows и в Ubuntu запускаю через консоль. Я подозреваю что проблема в установке JDK. Может быть кто-то знает в чем конкретно проблема?

```
while(snake.isAlive()) {
        snake.move(dir, apple);
        gp.repaint(); 
        try {
            Thread.sleep(70); // так регулируется скорость
        } catch(Exception ex) {}
    }


class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(backColor);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Width * Scale, Height * Scale);

        g.setColor(apple.color);
        while(!apple.rectSnakeFree(snake.coordX, snake.coordY)) { // пока не найдено свободного от змейки места на локации
            apple.randCoord(); // менять координаты
        }
        g.fillRect(apple.x * Scale, apple.y * Scale, Scale - 1, Scale - 1); // отрисовка яблока

        g.setColor(snake.color); // отрисовка змейки
        for(int i = 0; i < snake.len; i++) {
            g.fillRect(snake.coordX[i] * Scale, snake.coordY[i] * Scale, Scale - 1, Scale - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Так отрисовывается анимация

Если нужен код, вот ссылка на [github](https://github.com/KavyrshinR/MySnakeGame/tree/master/src).

Comment: Есть проблемы с производительностью — спрофилируйте. Положите часть кода, иллюстрирующую проблему, сюда (но не весь код, разумеется). Иначе на ваш вопрос ответят только те, кому не лень полезть на гитхаб (а таких немного).

Comment: А версии одинаковые? На линуксе openjdk или установщик скачанный с оракла?

Comment: @donRumata Скачанный с оракла

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На линуксе `paintComponent` вызывается стабильно, а вот отрисовка на экране действительно проходит с тормозами.

Используйте двойную буферизацию:

```
class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    private final Graphics2D G;
    private final BufferedImage buffer;

    public GamePanel() {
        buffer = new BufferedImage(Width * Scale, Height * Scale, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        G = buffer.createGraphics();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        draw(G);
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
    }

    private void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(backColor);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Width * Scale, Height * Scale);
        // ...
    }
}
```

С ней тормозов будет меньше.

Также цикл `while(snake.isAlive())` у вас вызывается в UI-потоке и блокирует его на 70 мс - не помешало бы вынести цикл и все проверки в отдельный поток.

И, наконец, если планируете обрабатывать клавиши в JPanel, помимо `requestFocus()` нужно установить `setFocusable(true)`.

```
gp.setFocusable(true);
gp.requestFocus();
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(snake.isAlive()) {
            while(!apple.rectSnakeFree(snake.coordX, snake.coordY)) {
                apple.randCoord();
            }
            snake.move(dir, apple);
            gp.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(70);
            } catch(Exception ex) {}
        }
    }
}).start();
```